# Python Port Listener

Tags: python

I would like to code a Python program that listens on a range of ports for incoming sin requests (possibly ack and fin as well). I then want this program to log the time, ip, and port of these sent packets.

Only thing is I really don't know where to start. I don't want anyone to hold my hand here, but I do need someone to point me in the right direction

Comment: evidently, most of this has already been done: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8148608/network-traffic-monitor-with-pcapy-in-python

Answer (score 3):

You are probably looking for raw sockets, see http://docs.python.org/library/socket.html

If you just want to capture received packets on a port range and log it, you should probably save yourself the trouble and use Wireshark http://www.wireshark.org/

Comment: My goal is to make a daemon I can run that will log connection attempts on common webserver and ssh ports. I know there are programs that do this already, but I want the experience coding it myself. Thanks for the link on Raw Sockets, ill check it out

Answer (score 1):

if it is for educational purposes; you could use [scapy](http://www.secdev.org/projects/scapy/doc/usage.html#interactive-tutorial) as a network sniffer. Otherwise just configuring your firewall to log appropriate events might be enough.

Comment: I think I am going to work with pcapy and lmpacket in order to do what I want. Thanks for the input guys