# how to get network traffic per connection using python

Tags: python, sockets, networking, monitor, traffic

I want to write a simple which-process-produces-which-network-traffic-monitor in python.

output should be something like this:

```
8479 (firefox)
     'stackoverflow.com' / 198.252.206.16:80 23 KiB/s
8130 (mono)
     '214-42-14-125.static.somedomain.net' / 204.62.14.135:443 127 KiB/s
```

So this should mainly do what **iftop** does. **psutil** comes very close to what
I need but it's lacking the actual traffic-per-connection information.

I know [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8148608/network-traffic-monitor-with-pcapy-in-python) post
and I'm currently going to use it for my purposes but I still hope that there is
something much simpler since I only want to get informed about the amount and
not the content of data being transferred.

So my actual question: is there a module for python which allows me to get the current data thruput for a given connection/socket of currently running processes?